# Sum of all data different than sum of individual data sets

Tags: sql, sql-server

What would cause SQL Server 2016 Express to return different results for the same data set when run individually vs summed all at once?

All transactions which are sales:

```
SELECT sum(transactionamount) 
FROM [NewPOS].[dbo].[Transaction] 
WHERE TransactionDateTime >= '2016-11-26 00:00:00' 
  AND TransactionDateTime <= '2017-11-27 0:0:0' 
  AND transactiontype = 0
```

Results in 134253

All transactions which are sales paid with payment type of cash:

```
SELECT sum(transactionamount) 
FROM [NewPOS].[dbo].[Transaction] 
WHERE TransactionDateTime >= '2016-11-26 00:00:00' 
  AND TransactionDateTime <= '2017-11-27 0:0:0' 
  AND transactiontype = 0  
  AND TransactionId IN (SELECT TransactionId 
                        FROM payment 
                        WHERE payment.PaymentType = 0)
```

Results in 56318.5

All transactions which are sales paid with payment type of credit card:

```
SELECT sum(transactionamount) 
FROM [NewPOS].[dbo].[Transaction] 
WHERE TransactionDateTime >= '2016-11-26 00:00:00' 
  AND TransactionDateTime <= '2017-11-27 0:0:0' 
  AND transactiontype = 0  
  AND TransactionId IN (SELECT TransactionId 
                        FROM payment 
                        WHERE payment.PaymentType = 2)
```

Results in 54054.5

All transactions which are sales paid with payment type of debit card:

```
SELECT sum(transactionamount) 
FROM [NewPOS].[dbo].[Transaction] 
WHERE TransactionDateTime >= '2016-11-26 00:00:00' 
  AND TransactionDateTime <= '2017-11-27 0:0:0' 
  AND transactiontype = 0  
  AND TransactionId IN (SELECT TransactionId 
                        FROM payment 
                        WHERE payment.PaymentType = 3)
```

Results in 28738.5

Add 56318.5 + 54054.5 + 28738.5 to get 139111.5

139111.5 is obviously != 134253

There is an extra 4858.5 in the summation of those three transaction types individually.

To validate I wasn't missing a payment type:

```
SELECT sum(transactionamount) 
FROM [NewPOS].[dbo].[Transaction] 
WHERE TransactionDateTime >= '2016-11-26 00:00:00' 
  AND TransactionDateTime <= '2017-11-27 0:0:0' 
  AND transactiontype = 0  
  AND TransactionId NOT IN (SELECT TransactionId 
                            FROM payment 
                            WHERE payment.PaymentType = 0 
                               OR payment.PaymentType = 2 
                               OR payment.PaymentType = 3)
```

It's probably something simple but I have been staring at these results, calculating things and can't figure out how these numbers are not adding up..

**Edit:**

Another verification query that the data being summed should be the same as individual queries:

```
SELECT sum(transactionAmount) 
FROM [NewPOS].[dbo].[Transaction] 
WHERE TransactionDateTime >= '2016-11-26 00:00:00' 
  AND TransactionDateTime <= '2017-11-27 0:0:0' 
  AND transactiontype = 0  
  AND TransactionId IN (SELECT TransactionId 
                        FROM payment 
                        WHERE payment.PaymentType = 0 
                           OR payment.PaymentType = 2 
                           OR payment.PaymentType = 3)
```

This query also results in 134253

**Edit 2:**

It appears that the check for multiple payment types failed to detect it --  I found the issue is most likely exactly that described in steenbergh's answer:

There are -cash and +debit transactions (cash back removes cash from drawer by adding a -cash payment, and a +debit payment for full amount + cash back..

This leads to really wacky numbers without filtering the cashback transaction numbers out, since there *are* transactions getting added twice once in cash, and once in debit..

Comment: It's difficult to say without seeing the actual data. My best guess is that you have transactions with multiple payment types. That would explain the result.

Comment: Wow.. I didn't even think of that.. while it is possible to do so, it is very rare that it happens, I'll look in to that one..

Comment: That it's a rare occasion is suggested by the comparably small difference in your numbers.

Comment: 2016, sorry was a typo..

Comment: are you really  sure that you don't some transcation id with more then a payement type?

Comment: Yes, I checked a few minutes ago - none during that time frame. There is an oddity in the way payments were done which is going to be addressed - and may be part of the problem, when paid with cash the payment amount is added then a -change amount so there are 2 payment records for each cash transaction (being addressed but can't touch it for another 2 weeks).. Would this throw off the summation in the above query?

Comment: @Richard, There is no way the query I've asked you to run returned 0 if this is the answer

Comment: @Richard, Damn.. I forgot to remove the WHERE from my copy-paste....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `payment` table has multiple records for some of your `TransactionID`s. This means that people paid in part with creditcard and in cash for the same transaction, for instance.

You can find this out with

```
select distinct TransactionID, count(*)
from Payment
group by TransactionID having count(*) > 1
order by 2 desc
```

This will show you all the Transactions where more than 1 method of payment was used.

This then influences your sum, because the `payment` table is only concerned with a part of those transactions, and the record in `Transactions` holds the full transaction amount. When you check that cash was used for (part of the) payment, and then take the full amount of the transaction, you also sum up the part paid for with a creditcard.

---

Assuming there's a column `Amount` or similar in the `payment` table, you could solve this problem with a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT sum(t.transactionamount) as Incorrect
, sum(p.amount) as Correct
FROM [NewPOS].[dbo].[Transaction] t
INNER JOIN [NewPOS].[dbo].[Payment] p on p.TransactionID = t.TransactionID
WHERE t.TransactionDateTime >= '2016-11-26 00:00:00' 
  AND t.TransactionDateTime <= '2017-11-27 0:0:0' 
  AND t.transactiontype = 0
  AND p.PaymentType = 0
```

To further make a breakdown to demonstrate how these tables interact:

```
SELECT distinct t.TransactionID
, p.PaymentType
, sum(p.amount) as [Amount paid with this type]
FROM [NewPOS].[dbo].[Transaction] t
INNER JOIN [NewPOS].[dbo].[Payment] p on p.TransactionID = t.TransactionID
WHERE t.TransactionDateTime >= '2016-11-26 00:00:00' 
  AND t.TransactionDateTime <= '2017-11-27 0:0:0' 
  AND t.transactiontype = 0
```

This query will list per transaction which types of payment were used, and for which amounts.

To further clarify, I've drawn you a picture:
[image]

It's **very** important to have a good understanding of `JOINS`, in any given database. for any type of system. Read up om 'm, do courses, search on YouTube.

Comment: I see your point, but the multiple transaction type tends to be extremely rare in this instance..

Comment: @Richard You now have an error of 3.5% which can be avoided completely. I strongly suggest altering your queries. I'll add a way to do this - assuming there's something of an amount in `payment` - to my answer.

Comment: While a valid point - unfortunately this isn't the problem here - multiple payment types were not used in that time frame.

Comment: Interesting... the query returns a different result than expected.. In my original query - is my assumption correct that it will only add the total once for each transaction id when summed all at once? ex: one transaction, two of the same payment type, would only be added once not twice

Comment: @Richard No; it adds the totals from the `payment` table. These are <> the totals of the `Transactions` table. You basically select all the transactions you're interested in from `Transactions` based on date and status etc, and then the amounts from `payment` per type.

Comment: I understand what your query does, but I am trying to ascertain why the totals are different in this scenario when *no* multiple payment types were used. -- My original query only summed the `TransactionAmount` which from my understanding should only add that amount once even if there there are two records for the same payment type - this being the case and that there are 0 multi tender transactions during that period, the number returned for a payment type summing transactionAmount -- should be the same as summing the payment amount and the same as the second query above, yet

Comment: The second query above shows Correct as 2230.00 for payment type zero, while my query returned 56318.50 - is the original query (in the question) summing the `Transactionamount` twice for having two records of the same payment type in the `Payment` table? If so - why?

Comment: I *understand* what you are saying and what your query does.. read my comment and you will see why I am confused my ORIGINAL query doesn't work when there are NO - ZERO - NADA multiple payment types! -- All transactions have ONE payment type for this time frame. Let me try it this way:

Comment: Transaction Id 18332 has ONE payment type of 0 - but two entries - 50 paid -48 change value (stupid yes, and I'm correcting it  soon) -- so, If I sum using the my ORIGINAL query - I expect I should get 2 for each query. since the transaction ID exists ins the select payment type sub query -- this is what is confusing me -- *not* what your query does or how joins work or any of that.. it's a simple -- I have transaction A and transaction B with ONE payment type (VERRIFED) and it is cash so there `SUM(Payment.Amount)' for those transaction SHOULD equal `SUM(TransactionAmount)`

Comment: @Richard It doesn't matter if it has only one payment type, what matters is how many rows any given `transactinID` has in `payment`.

Comment: Yet the results  are demonstrably different.. my original query only uses a `WHERE IN` clause which my understanding is it get checked once per record - therefore when `TransactionAmount = 2` and `SUM(P.paymentAmouint)` = 2 - why is `SUM(TransactionAmount) WHERE TransactionId IN (SELECT TransctionId FROM Payments WHERE PaymentType = 0) AND TransactionIDate [is in range] != 2`

Comment: Why does the number of rows matter in payment table when I'm summing TransactionAmount based on if the transactionid *exists* in the payments table? I'm not summing TransactionAmount based on the *number of times* it exists..

Comment: I apologize for the confusion here -- it appears that the check for multiple payment types above failed to detect it --  I found the issue is most likely exactly what you are describing here, because there are -cash and +debit transactions (cash back removes cash from drawer by adding a -cash payment, and a +debit payment for full amount + cash back.. Accepting this as the correct answer..

Comment: Nice try but the query you used to check duplication won't do the job. It indicates repetitions of the same TransactionID but does not indicate multiple paymenttype. The DISTINCT is meaningless.